# Hexagonal Architecture - How to update entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, domain-driven-design

I want to update a column in the database but everytime I call the update method a new column is being added in the database and it is not updating the specified column
I am trying to follow the Hexagonal architecture for my application I have the domain, application and persistence module.
This is my controller method in my application module:

```
    @PutMapping("/update/{propertyId}")
public ResponseEntity<PropertyResponseDTO> updateProperty(
        @PathVariable Long propertyId,
        @RequestBody PropertyUpdateDTO propertyUpdateDTO) {

    var propertyToUpdate = propertyServicePort.findById(propertyId).orElseThrow(()-> new ResourceNotFoundException("Property not found with Id" + propertyId));
    var update = propertyHttpMapper.update(propertyUpdateDTO,propertyToUpdate);
    propertyServicePort.update(propertyId, update);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(propertyHttpMapper.toDTO(update));
}
```

the property Http mapper looks like this:

```
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
@Mapping(target = "yearBuilt", source = "yearBuilt", qualifiedByName = "mapIntegerToYear")
@Mapping(target = "propertyType", ignore = true)
Property update(PropertyUpdateDTO source, @MappingTarget Property target);
```

And it does what it's supposed to do it generate all the setter method and null checks meaning that it is doing the mapping well.
Then I call the Property Service Update method which reside in my Port folder in the domain module and It looks like this:

```
    @Override
public Property update(Long propertyId, Property property) {
    return propertyDatabasePort.update(propertyId, property);
}
```

The propertyDatabase port resides in the spi of the domain module and this it's a propertyDatabaseAdapter which implements propertyDatabasePort and this is the implementation:

```
    @Override
@Transactional
public Property update(Long propertyId, Property property) {
    var propertyUpdate = exist(propertyId);
    propertyUpdate.setId(property.getId());
    return propertyMapper.toDomain(propertyRepository.save(propertyMapper.toEntity(property)));

}
```

And the issue is when I call the update function as I've mentioned new data is being added in the database and the specified column isn't being updated I think the way I mapped from PropertyUpdateDTO in the application layer up to Property in the domain module in the PropertyDatabaseAdapter to be exact it's good but the main issue is the propertyRepository.Save method which isn't updating the data.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the mapping before calling the save method.

```java
propertyRepository.save(propertyMapper.toEntity(property))
```

Here the entityManager interprets that it is a new object, you should follow the next steps:

1. get the object to modify `var result = repository.get(id)`
2. update the field in the same object `result.setName("newName")`
3. save the object update `repository.save(result)`

Comment: I don't want to use setters for each attribute as I have 15 attributes. The mapping is being done by the mapper method update and I already am passing the class Property with the updated attributes.

Comment: Can you check your impl mapping? Does the method return the same object or a new one ?